# C - Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion, scope

I'm writing a recursive program in C...

[image]

Given this structure for the expression "(1 + 3) * 2", how could I call the function E within F in the case of a parenthesis?  Obviously E would have to be declared before F.. but then how could I call F? I'm really stomped on this, I've got the programming working for all the cases without parenthesis but can't seem to figure this part out.

Comment: Can you explain some more of the logic? I don't follow.

Comment: Hint : convert your infix expression to postfix

Answer (score 3):

Just declare both function and the define them in the order you like.

It'll be something like this:

```
/*** header.h ***/
int E(int argument);
int F(int argument);

/*** source.c ***/
int E(int argument) {
    /* ... do smth ... */
    F(arg+1);
}

int F(int argument) {
    /* ... do smth ... */
    E(arg+1);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much haha.  I'm new to C, so I wasn't aware of this. This should work perfectly.

Comment: @user3106433 A good habit is to put those prototypes in an header file ;)